# Angular reactive form enable issue

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular reactive form with some disabled fields.
Initially the field is disabled programatically by the formbuilder.

```
this.parishDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  ...
  parish_no: [{value: '', disabled: true}],
  ...
});
```

The form is also disabled initially.After clicking a button the form is enabled (from another component)by

```
this.formGroup.enable();
```

But by doing so the disabled fields gets enabled.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: AFAIK disable and enable are recursive so it will always enable/disable all the fields. If you want to some fields to stay disabled you'd have to disable it manually. So it'd be `this.parishDetailsForm.get('parish_no').disable()` after you enabled form.

Comment: Create stackblitz and share the code.

Comment: you want to enable only certain fields in your formGroup?